# How to create a kiosk for steam?

Tags: games, steam, gdm, kiosk

I want to build kiosk for steam game app.

Mysystem info:-
OS - Ubuntu 20.04,.Gnome, GDM

Till now I did create a file

> /usr/share/xsessions/gameaccount

contains

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=game-session --session gameaccount
Type=Application
```

And a session file in

> /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gameaccount.session

```
[GNOME Session]
RequiredComponents=steam;
```

but user still need password to login, still able to use outher application like firefox. how to fix it?

I want to a steam here and anyone able to log here and play game.

On a side note I am just learning linux.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

I am still researching details, but this should work for you with Ubuntu 20.04, though you don't even need Gnome.

Please note I did this for browser (Chromium) and not Steam, so you may need to install additional packages if you start with Server image. You can still do this with Desktop image, just seems like an overkill for kiosk (you'd need to uninstall bunch of packages).

```
# I started with just Ubuntu Server, so I first installed basic Xorg packages
apt-get install xserver-xorg-core -y
# next install openbox, it is pretty basic window manager
apt-get install openbox -y
# install xinit and Steam
apt-get install xinit -y
apt-get install steam -y
# setup autologin so it acts as a kiosk
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/
nano /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
    [Service]
    Type=simple
    ExecStart=
    ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin YourUsername --noclear %I 38400 linux
# create or modify .profile script in your /home/YopurUsername to start X on login
nano .profile
    #Startx Automatically
    if [[ -z "$DISPLAY" ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
        . startx
        logout
    fi
# in same location create or edit .xinitrc which will start your app, eg, Steam
nano .xinitrc
    #!/bin/sh
    xset -dpms
    xset s off
    xset s noblank
    # the following starts Steam, you may look up if you can start it in Big Screen mode automatically
    steam
reboot
```

What I've found is:

- This will autologin as YourUser
- Will start Xorg and initialize openbox with almost zero bells and whistles
- Will start your app (Steam)
- If someone closes app it will restart immediately (will see short shell, but not enough to interact)
- Use unclutter if you want to remove the mouse cursor from screen (or hide it after idle=x seconds)

This is hardly a full blown solution, but it's a good start. Since you didn't say which game you are starting, I can just mention that maybe you can start Steam with some flags, starting game directly in fullscreen, couldn't find official article for Linux client, but this is link for Windows :
https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5623-QOSV-5250